# Como contactar um moderador?

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de saber como contactar um moderador, ou que um moderador pudesse ver a seguinte situação: parece que alguém resolveu sair negativando várias das minhas respostas, parece deliberadamente alguém de mal humor ou com raiva sei lá...

Posso oferecer evidencias, queria evitar por aqui no meta, mas basta ver a mudança de reputação, num instante vários negativos em respostas diversas. Obrigado e desculpem por aqui, mas não achei como contactar diretamente os moderadores.

Comment: Isso geralmente acaba sendo resolvido até o dia seguinte e o usuário é identificado para os moderadores tomarem providência.

Comment: Nesses casos pode sinalizar algumas das publicações negativadas em série com a opção _"precisa de atenção dos moderadores"_, que faz exatamente isso: alerta os moderadores :D - Aí você explica no texto, fica mais "discreto". No caso específico, o problema foi comprovado como um ataque pessoal, e já está sendo tratado na esfera correta. Estamos no aguardo da correção dos votos.

Comment: obrigado senhores, e a dica do @Bacco é uma boa ideia.. os votos de ontem foram revertidos, mas tive mais 2 seguidos logos após a reversão, vou sinalizar nas perguntas

Comment: Não sei quem foi, mas uma certeza eu tenho. A pessoa o odeia :D . Foram trinta e um votos em menos de três minutos.

Comment: :D @AugustoVasques eu tento ser educado nos comentários, não sou de sair distribuindo downvotes (num up, em 4 anos de SO, eu ganhei a medalha de Eleitorado esse ano), mas enfim sei lá, às vezes até de votar pra fechar as pessoas se ofendem, o importante é que foi revertido

Comment: Uma opção é chamar um mod chat

Comment: Ricardo, isso é uma questão muito desbotada de tanto ser comum no site. Chama-se "perseguição". Tem usuário que "não vai com a sua cara" e simplesmente entra no seu perfil e sai negativando tudo que vc postou, ou então, quando vc faz uma crítica a alguma postagem de um usuário e ele se sente ofendidinho e acha que foi vc que negativou a postagem dele, ele vai no seu perfil e negativa tudo.

Comment: Ou então, quando o cara não foi a sua cara (curioso isso, o cara nunca viu a sua cara de verdade rsrs), ele simplesmente negativa tudo que vc posta, seja uma pergunta ou resposta, ou analisa tudo com um critério que se vc errar uma vírgula, ele a negativa sorrindo, com o sentimento sórdido e covarde de que ninguém irá saber. Triste isso.